# How to uninstall a device?

Tags: usb, uninstall, hardware

Noob question time.

I had a USB device (a video grabber). I plugged it in and it installed itself automatically (it's listed in lsusb and it created /dev/video2 file). 
The device also created an additional soundcard.

Now I don't have this device anymore. How do I uninstall the device completely from my computer?
Is there any special command to do it? 
On Windows it was simple - just click 'Uninstall' in device manager. Is there something similar on Ubuntu?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking how to remove drivers, then you don't have to do anything.

When you plugged the device it, it didn't "install itself", but was detected by Linux kernel and necessary modules were loaded.

When there is no device, it will be detected by Linux automatically.

Comment: Oh, so that's how it works here. That's better than in Windows actually. I thought that the driver/module or whatever it's called in Linux, stays there until it's uninstalled. Cool to know. :)